# Spring Security - Enabled basic auth for just one nested resource

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security

I have an application with following resources ,

- POST /car
- Create API POST /car/{someId}
- Update API GET  /car/insurace
- POST /car/insurance-note - Required Basic AUTH

Only the last API needs basic auth , the rest above urls should allow everyone regardless if a "BASIC xxxx" . header is passed or not.

I have a configuration as follows,

```
http
                .antMatcher("/car/insurance-note")
                .httpBasic()
                .and().authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/car/**").permitAll();
```

This does allow access to other URLS regardless if I pass a BASIC header or not.
However , it also allows the car/insurance note in without a BASIC header.

Then I changed the configuration to ,

```
http.authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/car/insurance-note")
            .hasAuthority("USER")
            .and()
            .httpBasic()
            .and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/car/**")
            .permitAll();
```

Now , as well it looks like anytime a request has a "BASIC xxx" header the permit all does not work.

I am failing to get the logic of how this chaining works.

Answer (score 0):

In short, what you trying to do is to protect one endpoint, and allow the others, if I understood correctly. You can do something like this:

```java
http.authorizeRequests((requests) -> requests
    .antMatchers("/car/insurance-note").authenticated()
    .anyRequest().permitAll() // or antMatchers("/car/**").permitAll()
)
.httpBasic(Customizer.withDefaults());
```

Comment: This does not work. If I pass a Basic xxx header to the /car/** other endpoints it throws a unauthorized error although i have a permit all.

Comment: Is it a unauthorized 401 or 403? Enable trace level for logging and see what is the output. `logging.level.org.springframework.security=TRACE`

Comment: for the others URLs it throws a 401 if i pass a basic auth header. It looks like it applies httpbasic filter regardless.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer in case someone is looking for a case like this,

```
http.antMatcher("/car/insurance-note")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and().httpBasic();
```